# Audio player with fast startup time

Tags: audio, audio-player

I use IrfanView for any graphic files it supports simply because it has very fast startup time.

Is there any audio player software that has fast startup times?

I've been using Media Player and VLC, both take too long to launch a simply wav or mp3 file.

Comment: For what system?

Answer (score 1):

[1by1](https://mpesch3.de/1by1.html) is a small and lightweight file-system based music player for playing files, directories or whole drivers.

Startup speed will largely depend on you system capabilities, but being a small and simple player with a tiny download size, I'd expect it to have a relatively short startup time in most recent hardware.